# Not able to detect memory leak xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

I am writing a code for downloading image.I have a made a class of NSOperation type and I am calling that class. every thing is working fine but it is showing memory leak. I am not able to detect that.

Please help to get out of this problem. I am attaching an image with leak showing.[image]

I am adding a new image where you can see that I am simple initialising variable but it is still giving memory leak. I have a similar one more class for downloading image with @property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionHandler)(void);. I am also simple initialising it and not releasing but it is not giving any error. Please see below image.
[image]

If I am commenting [dowloader setcompletionhandler] block then it also showing this memory leak.Please see below image[image]

Comment: Try to remove the first initialization to nil and change it directly to your line 780. It looks like a false positive to me.

Comment: try by placing the last line that is adding to dictionary above the release method because u are adding to dictionary after releasing the iconDownloader

Comment: No, It is not the problem. At  one place I have call it simply, there also it is showing this type of memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Edited version:
Since you are using the object in the block, the block creates a strong reference. A strong reference in ARC means nothing more then retaining the object. Since you don't use ARC, you need to release the object you are using within the block manually when you are done. And yes, this is not a false positive.

Addition to Screenshot 3:
You constructed a different case now. You are now releasing an object you don't own. How does your the InitWithURL Method look like?

Perhaps you should convert this project to ARC to avoid such quarrels?

Comment: No this is not the case.I think I am using this @property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionHandler)(void); in AsyncImageDownloader class. I am also using this class before but not adding @ property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionHandler)(void); then its not showing memory leak but now I want to update table when image is downloaded.

Comment: Add NSLog(@"RetainCount: %@),@(downloader.retainCount)); statement in the completionblock and see what the count of the object is at runtime. It is 1 or higher, depends when the blocks executes. This is about threading. If you access an object from a block, the block needs to have a strong reference or better said, he makes sure the object stays alive. Else the object could be gone by the time the block executes since you did release it. Your block simply needs to release the object when he is done.

Comment: See this here at the end: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Fixed memory warning by changing the initialising code[image]
I don't know what is different b/w both but it solve the problem.

Comment: The difference is your implementation of the initWithURL versus the init you inherit from NSObject. Init retains the Object for the caller and your init does not. How does your InitWithURL method look like?

Comment: my initwithurl looks like 
-(id)initwithUrl:(NSURL *)theUrl forindexPath:(NSIndexPath *)theindexPath forPath:(NSString *)thePath forType:(int)Type
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        //code here
    }
    return self;
}